# Can't see navigation item for navigation bar in my scene outline or storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I can't see any navigation item in my scene outline for two view controllers and their views. The view controllers and scenes are meant to be connected to my navigation controller and a table view controller (which is embedded in the navigation controller) and I expected that I would see a navigation item under these views to represent the navigation bar. Maybe I'm wrong to expect that?

I embedded my table view controller in a navigation controller. This table view controller is connected to another view controller/scene called 'login' with a show segue, and this 'login' scene has a segue to a 'signup' scene.

*Note: I added those segues before I created a view controller class for both of the views so maybe this is what is making this happen? (not sure just want to include this info in case it helps solve this)*

Here's a screenshot of what this looks like on my storyboard:

[image: Screenshot from Storyboard]

You can see my navigation connected to a table view scene and then that table view controller connected to two other view controllers, as described.

Here is the scene outline:

[image: Scene Outline]

I guess I'm just wondering why there isn't an item in the login and signup scenes for a navigation bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to add one for that, by default there is not navigationbaritem added. You have to add items manually by drag n drop or programatically... 
Hope it helps!

Comment: its my pleasure, happy iOS Programming!

Answer (score 13):

I solved it by changing the Segue's type "Show" to "Push" (deprecated), and then returning to "Show".

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a navigation item to the view controller.

Once your view controller has a navigation item you can then add bar buttons to the navigation bar, which you can use to perform segues or other actions.